# Resizable columns tables with fixed header

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web

I'm trying to create a table with resizable columns and fixed header.
But when I'm trying to drag the header column, table columns change their size, but some gap is created.

For example:
[image: initial]

What I get after dragging:
[image: dragged]

My sample:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#tableHeader').colResizable({
        liveDrag: true,
        onDrag: resFun
    });


    function resFun() {
        var c1 = $('#c1').width();
        var c2 = $('#c2').width();
        var c3 = $('#c3').width();

        $('.c1').width(c1);
        $('.c2').width(c2);
        $('.c3').width(c3);

    };

    resFun();
});
</script>

<div style="padding-right: 17px; height: 39px;">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="tableHeader" style="width: 100%; height: 39px;">
        <tr>
            <th id="c1">first</th>
            <th id="c2">second</th>
            <th id="c3">third</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div style="overflow: auto; height: 200px;">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="table">
        <tr>
            <td class="c1">col 1</td>
            <td class="c2">col 2</td>
            <td class="c3">col 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="c1">col 1</td>
            <td class="c2">col 2</td>
            <td class="c3">col 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="c1">col 1</td>
            <td class="c2">col 2</td>
            <td class="c3">col 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="c1">col 1</td>
            <td class="c2">col 2</td>
            <td class="c3">col 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="c1">col 1</td>
            <td class="c2">col 2</td>
            <td class="c3">col 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="c1">col 1</td>
            <td class="c2">col 2</td>
            <td class="c3">col 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="c1">col 1</td>
            <td class="c2">col 2</td>
            <td class="c3">col 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="c1">col 1</td>
            <td class="c2">col 2</td>
            <td class="c3">col 3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, realizable columns but fixed headers?? Can you please explain how this is possible or give an example of what you mean? The header will have to be the same as the column otherwise the table will not make sense.

Comment: as you can see at screenshots, header is not overflowed. You can scroll the table, but its header will be always at top.

Comment: Oh Fixed on to the page I see, I thought you meant fixed in width. My bad! what plugin are you using to resize the columns, is it jQuery UI?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use `th` in your first table... it won't make it part of the second. You just have 2 different tables and, as so, the cells width will change according with the content inside. You have to set a fixed width for the cells if you want to have the "effect" of both tables beign just one...

Comment: Josh, I'm using this plugin: http://jquer.in/random-jquery-plugins-for-superior-websites/colresizable/

Comment: Alvaro, as you can see, there is onDrag event at the first table and function, that changes cols width at the second table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the cells of the second table have a padding set and the cells of the header doesn't.. add padding to the header as well and should be ok